# How to run specific 'it' blocks in protractor

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Created a spec file with combination of test cases ('it' blocks), the definition will be as below:

**spec1.js**

```
describe('suite', function(){

  it('test case1', function()
   {
      //test case definition
   })

   it('test case2', function()
   {
      //test case definition
   })
})
```

conf.js setup is as below.

```
suites: {
       suite1: [
           path.resolve(filePath.specFile1),
           path.resolve(filePath.specFile2),
           path.resolve(filePath.specFile3)
            ]
        suite2:
            [
           path.resolve(filePath.specFile1),
           path.resolve(filePath.specFile3)
            ]
      }
```

The commands to trigger in package.json as

```
"suite1test": "protractor ./conf.js --suite suite1",
"allTest" : "protractor ./conf.js"
```

from the command line, we can trigger suite1 as "`npm run suite1test`"

But my requirement is, I want to execute 'test case1' 'it' block only from spec1.js like that specific test cases from the spec files and make a group as a test suite.

When I search for the solution, I got it that we can disable some test case or suite by preceding with 'x' i.e., 'xdescribe' disables that suite and 'xit' will disable particular 'it' block

If want to execute a particular test suite or test case then we can be preceding with 'f' focus i.e., 'fdescribe' will execute that suite and 'fit' will execute that particular 'it' block.

This is a lengthy process if want to create a separate set of a test suite or test cases that want to execute, each and every time, we need to change on each spec file level. Instead of this, want to trigger from the conf.js by creating separate suites pointing to particular 'it' blocks and trigger when it required.

Is there any solution for these?

Answer (score 1):

You need separate spec files and then you can call them in spec from conf.js. 
It is not good practice to add x or f and change it all the time.

Comment: Is there any other way other than separate into different spec files? If we create separate into different spec files then we define it under 'describe' and it shows those scenarios as test suites in reports, I want all of these as one test suite, not as different test suites in the report.

Comment: If you use Cucumber with protractor, you can implement tags in features @Smoke etc and run only tests that are part of the tag specified.